# Retrieve a list of downloadable content from a website in java

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android app to fetch some files from the internet. The website contains a list different files which you can download. It also contains some subfolders with files. Is there a way to get a list of the filenames and links so a user can choose which ones to downloade from my app?

Comment: If the HTML is consistent, you might need to parse the HTML and get the required links.

Answer (score 0):

If the website displays the information via HTML, you can screen scrap the HTML with a library like JSoup [1]  If they allow directory listings you can parse that too to show the user this information. It depends on the API exposed by the website to display the files.

[1] - http://jsoup.org/